# Does TensorFlow provide a half normal initialiser?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, initialization, tensorflow2.0, initializer

TensorFlow provides the [`random_normal_initializer`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random_normal_initializer). However, I need an initializer that produces numbers between `0` and `N`, but that puts more density around a certain value `x` (chosen by the user) in the range `[0, N]` (where `N` can be `1`), so I cannot use the uniform initializer (because it puts mass equally on all values).

I think that an initializer that produces an [`HalfNormal`](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/distributions/HalfNormal) would be ok.

Does TF already provide this or do I need to implement a custom initializer?

If I need to implement a custom initializer, what's the typical way of doing that? I guess I can inherit from the [initializer class](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.1.0/tensorflow/python/ops/init_ops_v2.py#L47), but I don't know if this is a common way of doing things.

This issue was also [raised in the TF's issue tracker](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/38727).

Answer (score 0):

According to [this documentation page](https://keras.io/initializers/), we can implement a custom initializer by defining a function that returns an initial value. We then pass this function object (i.e. you do not call the function) to the initializer.

Here's an example (in TensorFlow 2.1) that does what I want.

```
import tensorflow as tf


def random_half_normal(shape, **kwargs):
    return tf.abs(tf.keras.backend.random_normal(shape, **kwargs))


class MyLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.my_var = self.add_weight(initializer=random_half_normal, 
                                      trainable=False)

    def call(self, inputs):
        tf.print("\nself.my_var =", self.my_var)
        return inputs


def get_model():
    inp = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,))
    out = MyLayer(8)(inp)
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inp, outputs=out)
    model.summary()
    return model


def train():
    model = get_model()
    model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="mae")
    x_train = [2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 6]
    y_train = [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
    model.fit(x_train, y_train)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    train()
```